# To view or not to view

Tags: php, mysql, view

This may be a simple and silly question for some, but i'm trying to figure what would be the best way to tackle the next problem. I have the following database in MySQL:

[image: my personal webpage database]

As you can see, there is a "general table" called resources, and a table that contains each type of resource (blog entries, images, videos, etc ... ), i would like to know if its worth it to create a view for each type of resource (blog view, video view ...) that i can then query to get the information an populate each webpage, or if its better to just query the table directly, as well as the "associated" tables (say, query resources table, and select the type of resource where the id = id of the resource table, and then query tag table to get the tags where the id = id of resource, and so on).

Also, i would like to know what the best way to update this tables would be, is there some sort of "cascade update" so i can update/input information into the tables at the same time, or should i do it by using several queries, say, "insrte X into resources, get the of that insert, then insert the tags on tag table, get the ids, then fill resurces tag table, and so on).

Some additional information, i'm using PHP, would it be better to create objects for each on of this "views"/"queries" that would represent each type of resource ?.

Comment: you can't do multi-table inserts. you'll have to do individual inserts, get that insert's ID, use that in subsequent IDs, etc...

Comment: just what i thought, i was wandering if it was possible, sort of what you do using entity framework. thanks.

Comment: entity frameworks serve to hide the fact, but they're still doing single-table inserts in sequence behind the scenes.

Comment: Noted, all this time thinking it was some sort of magic code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Views:*

Practically speaking, you should be totally fine without implementing views. You can use **joins** in order to select associated relationships.

*Updating:*

You will have to use multiple inserts in order to update tables. If you're worried about information integrity, you can do this via a **transaction** which would guarantee all inserts succeeding, or getting rolled back.

*On a side note:*

Given the current schema, you can put the create_time/update_time columns on the resources table to simplify things.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, i figure that it would be OK to not have views, i was just wondering if they would be any time saver when querying the database, or maybe a better idea instead of having the query with joins directly querying the table.

Comment: @Q_ro My understanding is that it just does the join in background for you, so there's no saving in terms of performance. The main purpose is to remove complexity from writing applications on top of the DB.